# Add a suffix to a character string every n elements

Tags: r, string

I have a vector with character elements that looks like this:

```
vec <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
```

I want to add a suffix to each element in `vec` denoting how many times the element is repeated, the output should be something like this:

```
>vec1
[1] "A_1" "A_2" "A_3" "B_1" "B_2" "B_3" "C_1" "C_2", "C_3"
```

I have tried with the following but it doesn't work

```
sapply(vec, function(x) paste(x, seq(1,3,1), sep="_"))
```

Comment: How about `paste(vec,1:3,sep="_")` ?

Comment: I was doing the most complicated thing ever, please write your comment as an answer and I will give you the points, thanks

Comment: `how many times the element is repeated` does this not mean the output should be `A_3,A_3,A_3,B_3,B_3,B_3,C_3,C_3,C_3`, as each element is repeated 3 times.

Comment: Also note the existence of `make.unique`, which doesn’t *quite* do the same, but is very similar in spirit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using paste:

```
paste(vec,1:3,sep="_")
```

When we do not know how many times each letter is repeated.

```
# dynamic version
paste(vec,
      unlist(sapply(as.numeric(table(vec)),
                    function(i) seq(1,i,1))),
      sep="_")
```

As @Jay suggested simpler dynamic version

```
paste(vec,sequence(rle(vec)$lengths), sep="_")
```

Comment: An alternative, and I think simpler, dynamic version would be `paste(vec, sequence(rle(vec)$lengths), sep="_")`

Comment: Another option is `library(splitstackshape);paste(vec,getanID(vec)$.id,sep='_')`

Answer (score 1):

This works even if the numbers of "A"'s, "B"'s, etc. are distinct:

```
vec <- c(rep("A",3),rep("B",5),rep("C",2))

n <- c("",vec[-length(vec)]) != vec
m <- (1:length(vec)) * n
idx <- (1:length(vec))-cummax(m)+1

v <- paste(vec,idx,sep="_")
```

.

```
> vec
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C"
> n
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> m
 [1] 1 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 9 0
> idx
 [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 1 2
> v
 [1] "A_1" "A_2" "A_3" "B_1" "B_2" "B_3" "B_4" "B_5" "C_1" "C_2"
>
```

In contrast:

```
> paste(vec,1:3,sep="_")
 [1] "A_1" "A_2" "A_3" "B_1" "B_2" "B_3" "B_1" "B_2" "C_3" "C_1"
>
```